# How can I use jQuery .on() method in a loop, without overriding the objects on which I loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have to assign `mousedown` events to an objects collection.

But the `.on()` method seems to override my objects on each turn.

Here's a very simplified example of what I have in my code.

The JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArray = {
        0: {"id": "box1", "color": "blue"},
        1: {"id": "box2", "color": "green"}
    };
    
    for (i in myArray) {
        box = $('div#'+myArray[i]['id']);
        color = myArray[i]['color'];
        box.data('color', color);
        box.on({
            mousedown: function() {
                var color = myArray[i]['color'];
                $(this).css({'background': $(this).data('color')});
                myArray[i]['color'] = (i==0) ? "orange" : "pink";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and the HTML:

```
​<div id="container">
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​In addition, you can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/ae3En/6/

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: You sure you're just not losing `i` because of how JS works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` to iterate over the array and avoid all scope problems through that:

```
$.each(myArray, function(i, obj) {
    $('div#'+obj['id']).on({
        mousedown: function() {
            $(this).css({'background': obj['color']});
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice Felix, it seems to be what I'm looking for. I always forget this .each() method. I'll try this tomorrow, it's too late for me now. I'll say you if it's ok or not. Thanks.

Comment: OK it works ! Thank you Felix. For those who have the same problem here's my code now : http://jsfiddle.net/ae3En/9/

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `box` in the function (and `box` is defined externally).  Thus, it will always refer to the last bound box.  Has nothing to do with `.on` specifically.  A few ways to handle this, but the easiest is:

```
mousedown: function () {
   $(this).css(...)
}
```

EDIT: I'm not entirely sure why it only uses the last color from the variable.  I was able to get around this by binding the anticipated color to the div itself using `.data`.  Hope this solution works for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/ae3En/5/

Comment: Ok thanks, it's working now. But I've too much simplified my code example. In fact I need to re-assign new colors to my array after that. This is what I really need to do : http://jsfiddle.net/ae3En/6/
I will Edit my question right now.

Comment: @Twist what do you mean?  Do you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

SMALL CHANGE IN YOUR CODE:
REPLACE THIS LINE

```
box.css({'background': myArray[i]['color']});
```

BY

```
  $(this).css({'background': myArray[i]['color']});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Both boxes turn green. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ae3En/2/

Comment: That's right, I could use `$(this)` but as @j08691 says, both boxes turn green.

Comment: this is because for both mosuedown callbacks, both refer to i which is '1'. what you need is to declare new variable with same value of i in the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Your mousedown code isn't being triggered until after the loop has been run, so you're always assigning the last object. This works: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ae3En/4/)**.

```
var myArray = {
    "0": { "id": "box0","color": "blue" },
    "1": {"id": "box1", "color": "green" }
};
$('#container div').each(function(i) {
    $(this).on({
        mousedown: function() {
            $(this).css({
                'background': myArray[i]['color']
            });
        }
    })
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I said it's a very simplified sample of my code. I really need to loop on myArray not on $('#container div').

Answer (score 0):

you can also send your current box variable to a listener function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArray = {
        "0": {"id": "box1", "color": "blue"},
        "1": {"id": "box2", "color": "green"}
    };
    function listener(box,i)
    {
        box.on({
            mousedown: function() {
                box.css({'background': myArray[i]['color']});
            }
        });
    }
    for (i in myArray) {

        var box  = $('div#'+myArray[i]['id']);
        listener(box,i);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArray = {
        "0": {"id": "box1", "color": "blue"},
        "1": {"id": "box2", "color": "green"}
    };

    for (i in myArray) {
        var box = $('div#'+myArray[i]['id']);
        var color = myArray[i]['color'];
        box.data('color', color);

        box.on({
            mousedown: function() {
                $(this).css({'background': $(this).data('color')});
            }
        });
    }
});
```

​

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ae3En/7/)